# French literature : mixed usage of historic and imperfect

Tags: imparfait, passé-simple

I understand that French literature uses past historic. But I also see some imperfect used mixed with past historic in literature. Without hopefully violating copyright with the below sample, here is an example from Harry Potter official translation :

> Elle donna un affectueux coup de bec à Harry tandis qu'il lui
>   enlevait son  fardeau, puis elle traversa la pièce d'un coup d'aile
>   pour rejoindre Errol.

Here, "donna" is historic and "enlevait" is imperfect. What is the difference in meanings of these past tenses when they are mixed ?

Answer (score 2):

In effect, when reading French literature that uses the *passé simple*:

- The *passé composé* is replaced by the *passé simple*, except in dialogue and similar text intended to directly represent speech. (I'm quite sure that Harry and the other characters do not use the *passé simple* in their speech.)
- The *imparfait* remains the *imparfait*. In all cases in which you would use the *imparfait* in spoken French, it shows up in written French.

In other words, the general difference between the *passé composé* and the *imparfait* that you learn remains, except that the *passé simple* is used instead.

In your example, the contemporary natural spoken way to say that sentence would be:

> Elle **a donné** un affectueux coup de bec à Harry tandis qu'il lui enlevait son fardeau, puis elle **a traversé** la pièce d'un coup d'aile pour rejoindre Errol.

- *Donna/a donné* represents a completed action (she gave him a peck and it was done)
- *Enlevait* is in the *imparfait* because Harry "was taking off" the burden, an action that is ongoing. You would use the *imparfait* in spoken French in the same way.
- *Traversa/a traversé* also represents a completed action (she crossed the room).

Comment: Good answer, but notice that “ongoing” actions are one but not the only use of imparfait. A state, a description or a recurrent event, a habit would be rendered using imparfait as well. An alternative way to think about it is to consider that the simple past is used for narrative steps and imparfait is used for context.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the "coup de bec" (how do you say this in English?) being quick, it is in the "passé simple" (historic past).

On the other hand, taking off the burden from the animal lasts a bit, and is therefore in the "imparfait" (imperfect).

This is the usual distinction for "passé simple" and "imparfait".

Similar sentence and usage in English, with past continuous instead of "imparfait", and preterit instead of "passé simple" : 
    She gave him a quick kiss while he was taking off his raincoat.